# .htaccess Header command produces error 500 when using escaped URLs

Tags: .htaccess, encoding, urlencode, http-status-code-500

I have lots of web pages which seperately exist as PDF files. I was asked to tell Google via .htaccess what the original HTML version URL of the PDF files is.

All web pages are available via an encoded URL using PHP's `urlencode()` function. The URLs contain company names.

---

**Working example**, company name "Very good company":

```
<Files company123.pdf>
    Header append Link '<https://www.example.com/company/123/Very+good+company>; rel="canonical"'
</Files>
```

---

Once the company name contains a character that needs to be encoded (e.g. German umlauts), the web server delivers an error 500 for the whole directory:

**Non-working example**, company name "Very bäd cömpäny":

```
<Files company456.pdf>
    Header append Link '<https://www.example.com/company/456/Very+b%C3%A4d+c%C3%B6mp%C3%A4ny>; rel="canonical"'
</Files>
```

---

What do I have to change to solve this problem? Is it wrong that the file contains encoded URLs? Do I have to define unencoded URLs like `https://www.example.com/company/123/Very good company` and `https://www.example.com/company/123/Very bäd cömpäny` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header

> value may be a character string, a string containing mod_headers specific **format specifiers** (and character literals), or an ap_expr expression prefixed with expr=

The percent character is part of this format specifier syntax, so you need to escape it:

> ```
> The following format specifiers are supported in value:  
> Format   Description  
> %%       The percent sign  
> …        …
> ```

You will need to double all the `%` characters here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the first time I work with Apache's header module, even had to install the module first. Never heard of those format specifiers, so thanks again!